# FormData is not appending file object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function that is executed after the onChange event for `<input type="file/>`. The `dataz` variable is empty after `console.log(dataz)` and the `axios.post`

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input');

input.addEventListener('change', handlefileupload);

function handlefileupload(e) {
  var dataz = new FormData();
  dataz.append('file', e.target.files[0]);
  
  console.log(dataz);
  
  /* Note to OP: you dont need to actually include code like
     this, it has nothing to do with your question/problem
     
  axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/upload_document', {
      files: dataz
    }, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + sessionStorage.getItem('loginToken'),
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }
    })
    .then((response) => {
        console.log('success')

      }
    )
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error.response);
    });
  */
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="input" />
```

This is what I get in my `console.log(dataz)`

```
FormData {}
__proto__: FormData
append: ƒ append()
delete: ƒ delete()
entries: ƒ entries()
forEach: ƒ forEach()
get: ƒ ()
getAll: ƒ getAll()
has: ƒ has()
keys: ƒ keys()
set: ƒ ()
values: ƒ values()
constructor: ƒ FormData()
Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ entries()
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "FormData"
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking. Are you saying you don't get the file on the server, or that it's null somewhere in there? Please [edit] your question to include what you're expecting and what's happening. See [ask] for more information.

Comment: Its null after console.log and server

Comment: does e.target.files[0] have content?

Comment: Yes it does if you do console.log on it

Comment: I added a snippet, try it again because it's not empty for me. It shouldn't matter if it's method or function, should work the same way, as long as you pass correct `event` to it.

Comment: I am using ruby on rails

Comment: Server has nothing to do with it if OP commented that `console.log` is also empty. You must be leaving something important out, please include your whole component (but remove axios code, it's not related).

Answer (score 0):

The event handler for action on an input field is called 'input'. So I suspect what you want it:

```
input.addEventListener('input', handlefileupload);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `console.log(dataz)` to show `FormData` values. Instead of this use the following:

```
    for (let val of dataz.values()) {
        console.log(val);
    }
```